# laravel find matching id and assign a specific field value to variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I am looking for a matching business using eloquent. I get a matching result and now I want to use specific field, assign it to variable so I can retrieve user twitter.

Here's my code:

```
    $business = Business::with('addresses')
                    ->find($id);
    $variable = $business->business_twitter;
    $test = Twitter::getUserTimeline(['screen_name' => $variable, 'count' => 20, 'format' => 'json']);
    dd($variable);
```

However, dd($variable) is apparently empty. How can this be tackled?

//edit

dd($business);

```
Business {#232 ▼
  #table: "businesses"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 97
    "name" => "telephone"
    "type" => "4"
    "email" => "p.wojtas26@gmail.com"
    "logo" => null
    "twitter_business" => "live_oldham"
    "facebook_business" => "liveoldham"
    "instagram_business" => "live_oldham"
    "image" => null
    "gallery_id" => null
    "user_id" => 2
    "api_key" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-06-20 10:10:38"
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-20 10:10:38"
```

Comment: review your table once that you have data in it?

Comment: Yeap I do have the data, I am sure of it

Comment: dd($business) returning result?

Comment: see an edit just to prove that it does

Comment: Have you defined `addresses ()` function in Business Model ?

Comment: yes I did but it has nothing to do with what I am trying to do. I just need to attach business_twitter retrieved to a variable in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing mistake while fetching key. You should fetch `twitter_business` key from your `$business` collection.

```
$variable = $business->twitter_business;
```